# How effective are pancake motors as generators and why

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, electrical

Using a motor as a generator but  looking to test something 
Why would or would they not be good generators 
thanks

Comment: What is your definition of "effective? effective can mean it fits in the space or exceeds a given power density etc

Answer (score 3):

DC motors make fine generators. You can test them by connecting the shaft of the motor to the chuck of a variable-speed electric drill and connecting the motor wires to a load resistor; you then measure output current and voltage as functions of drill speed.

Comment: An simple testing method... The load resistor can be as simple as a car headlight bulb  ie 12V and 55W etc